# OpenLayers: OSM doesn't show up on div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, openlayers

I'm trying to load the map content from OpenStreetMaps into a div inside my hybrid mobile app, using the following code:

-JS:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $cordovaGeolocation, Util)
                {

            if (! $scope.firstloaded)
            {
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");

             var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

             var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

             // Transform from WGS 1984
             var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

             // to Spherical Mercator Projection
             var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.41,52.52).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

             var zoom = 15;

             map.addLayer(mapnik);
            map.setCenter(position, zoom );

            $scope.firstloaded = true;
            }
```

-HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Location</span>
      <div id="basicMap" style="height:250px"></div>
    </label>
```

.. However, I don't know why the map is not showing on the div.

So, is there anything wrong with the code?
How is it possible to fix this problem?

Comment: You may need to checkout the Ionic whitelist plugin for allowing requests to particular domains, also any DOM manipulation in angular should be done in a directive, would search to see if there is a good angular directive for open street maps or start working on one.

Comment: @shaunhusain whitelist plugin is already installed. this is the used configuration: `<content src="index.html"/>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" source="npm" />

  <access origin="*"/>

  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />`

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo the npm module didn't load correctly, it failed with the following error: "Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module openlayers-directive due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'openlayers-directive' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it."

Comment: @user6039980 regarding the error you wrote it means the script that defines angular.module('openlayers-directive', []) wasn't loaded for some reason.  Check to be sure your index.html includes a script tag for it and that it's able to load (check the network panel to see the script that defines that module is loaded and it's response contents have the definition of the module)

Comment: @shaunhusain I've tried what you've recommended, with `<script src="bower_components/angular-openlayers-directive/dist/angular-openlayers-directive.js"></script>` , and there is no error, but the map didn't show up: so that simply didn't work.

Comment: @user6039980 One thing i have noted here is that you have not posted the complete code. Also you have to first try out thr simple sample and see if it works. Check out this - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example

Comment: @Gandhi Thank you for your reply. .. And using the code example on the whole index.html made the maps work perfectly. BTW, I found that the exclusion of the CSS code (being used at the example) caused the map loading fail. Now, after including that code, all the maps worked fine without any problem! That was really helpful from your part, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the simple example as mentioned in the following [OpenStreetMap Example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example).

Once it works you can extend the same with your implementation as it will have all the prerequisite of a working code base which can be enhanced.